# Ansible WinRM Server did not response with a CredSSP token after step Step 5

Tags: ansible, winrm, credssp

I am using Ansible (2.9.6) to connect Windows server using WinRM CredSSP. for win ping command its giving server did not response with CredSSP token. CredSSP enabled on the clinet machine

`ansible windows -i hosts  -m win_ping`

```
 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "credssp: Server did not response with a CredSSP token after step Step 5. Delegate Credentials - actual 'Negotiate, Kerberos, CredSSP'",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Any help to resolve this error message?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the below error

`msg: 'credssp: Server did not response with a CredSSP token after step Step 5. Delegate Credentials - actual '''''`

after updating pywinrm to 0.4.2 the issue was resolved

Comment: I'm having the same CredSSP issue. Where did you find pywinrm 0.4.2? The latest version on PyPi and on the project's GitHub page is 0.4.1.  Are you using a fork?

Answer (score 2):

On the Windows server set the Credssp to `true`. Open powershell as administrator and paste the below commands:

```
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{CredSSP="true"}'

winrm set winrm/config/client/auth '@{CredSSP="true"}'

Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server
```

Then you will be able to get:

```
 SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
```

for the `ansible windows -i hosts  -m win_ping` command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PSRP to a Windows 2012R2 server and I have the same issue on a win_copy task, but win_ping works. That didn't make any sense, then I disabled the Antivirus (McAfee) and the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Below commands are helps me to resolve the credssp issue, Thankyou
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{CredSSP="true"}'

winrm set winrm/config/client/auth '@{CredSSP="true"}'

Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server